# What is wrong with this logic tree?

Tags: logic

I have found this in a university text book and have been told it has many erros. What is wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $Pb$ and $Qb$ magically appear and $\forall x(Px\to Qx)$ is improperly instantiated. The $(\neg Qb\wedge\forall x(Px\to Qx))$ should be negated (as should $Px$) and it's treated like $\vee$ instead of $\wedge$.

Each path of a tableau kind of represents a different scenario, so that what happens in one path doesn't influence what happens in another beyond the point where they branch.

Here's what I get:

[image].

Comment: Does this answer your question, @Joseph? $\ddot\smile$

Comment: [The code for the diagram above is available on request, but it'll take a while.]

Comment: Sure it does, great! I just could not believe when I was told its in a textbook as an example! The code would be great, but as I don't need it specifically, I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 0):

This tree is fine, but it's not a tableau, it's syntax tree. Whoever told you it's wrong is confusing tableaux (which represent ways a formula can be falsified) and syntax trees (which represent the syntactic structure of a formula, breaking it down in simpler sub-formula until you reach atomic formula).